# Android Manifest.XML File looks odd and I cannot seem to get it in a readable format

Tags: android-studio, apk

So I have been tinkering around with a few android apps. For some reason the text within them looks like a bunch of random symbols almost like garbage text. I tried messing around with the unicode but I can't figure out what's causing this. Thoughts??

[Manifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf5z9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AndroidManifest.xml file is only XML in the source code. Once you compile the app, it gets compiled into a binary format that is more efficient for the Android platform to read from.

This format is undocumented but there are multiple attempts at reverse engineering the source code, e.g. https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/android-internals-binary-xml-part-one-example/

Or if all you need is see what's in the manifest, you can simply use `aapt2` (shipped as part of Android platform tools) with the command `aapt2 dump xmltree app.apk --file AndroidManifest.xml`